# Php tags display

Tags: php, tags

There are 4 tables used for storing tags:

```
tagovi, tagovi_vijesti, tagovi_blogovi, tagovi_dogadjanja
```

Structure od table `tagovi`:

```
id - name
```

Structure of table `tagovi_vijesti`:

```
id - vijesti_id - tag_id
```

The same is for other two tables.

On main page I display tags from all three tables this way:

```
$sql = "SELECT
            T.id AS id, T.name AS tag,
            TV.id AS tag_vijest_id, TD.id AS tag_dogadjanje_id, TB.id AS tag_blog_id,
            COUNT(*) ponavljanje
            FROM tagovi AS T
            LEFT JOIN tagovi_vijesti AS TV ON T.id = TV.tag_id
            LEFT JOIN tagovi_dogadjanja AS TD ON T.id = TD.tag_id
            LEFT JOIN tagovi_blogovi AS TB ON T.id = TB.tag_id
            WHERE TV.id IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY id
            ORDER BY id DESC
            LIMIT 35"; 
    $sql_result = mysql_query($sql,$connect)
        or die("Upit nije izvrsen");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)){
        $tag_id = $row["id"];
        $tag_url = $row["tag"];
        $tag = preg_replace('/-/', ' ', $tag_url);
        $tag_ponavljanje = $row["ponavljanje"]; 

        if($tag_ponavljanje >= 10 && $tag_ponavljanje < 20) $fontSize = "14px";
        elseif($tag_ponavljanje >= 20 && $tag_ponavljanje < 30) $fontSize = "16px";
        elseif($tag_ponavljanje >= 30 && $tag_ponavljanje < 40) $fontSize = "18px";
        elseif($tag_ponavljanje >= 40 && $tag_ponavljanje < 60) $fontSize = "20px";
        elseif($tag_ponavljanje >= 60) $fontSize = "24px";
        else $fontSize = "12px";

        echo " &nbsp; <a href = \"$ispisi_link/tag/$tag_url\" style=\"font-size: $fontSize;\">$tag</a> &nbsp; ";
    }
```

But I don't think that this is the perfect way to do it because tags are sorted by id and then all those old tags will never be displayed again because results are sorted by id. What kind of display (query) do you use? What would you advise me about displaying tags? Is it better to sort them by number of repeating of each tag (in my table repeating is called "ponavljanje")? If I use this way then I'm bit afraid that there will be tags that will be repeated in most of content and new one will never be displayed on main page. Or should I maybe use two queries, one for new tags and one for those who are mostly used?

Thanks,
Ile

Comment: I think this example shows why English-only variable names are to be preferred. :-P

Comment: I think it's not hard to conclude what 'tagovi' or 'blogovi' means :P :D

Comment: @ile +1, but tagovi_vijesti is a little harder to grok

Comment: @Jonathan: I think that meaning of it is totally irrelevant in this story, it's clear that this is some table's name and name of this table could be anything... I'm pretty sure everyone understands my question, no matter variable name and that's what matters here :) Usually I translate variable names if that's necessary...

Comment: Understanding the variable names is a huge help in understanding the problem. If this wasn't the case, we all could name our variable names `v001` through `v999` and be happy with it. ;-)

Comment: that's right, generally said, but in this case I don't think it's important... or you think it would change something if tagovi_vijesti was called tags_news? :))

Answer (score 2):

You could mix it up by combining both into a single table (that way you have the best of both worlds).

So if you were going to do a tag cloud of 20 tags, select the 10 most tagged and 10 random ones.

ORDER BY RAND() is going to be pretty rough if you have lots of tags though as Arkh mentioned.  Alternatively you could insert each tag with a random integer and then have that column indexed.  If you want to shuffle the tags around later you could reassign random values to that column.

Comment: Is there other (easier) way to select 10 most tagged and then select 10 random ones excluding 10 most tagged than this I would use:
Store ids from 10 most tagged to array and then in sql query exclude it with "WHILE foreach ($ids as $id) id!='$id'" (this is just to explain semantics, I know syntax is wrong :))
And maybe I could add even 10 latest tags, so it would be total od 30 tags... I think that this would be good solution.
Thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use ORDER By RAND() ?
It may kill your perfs, but if you cache the result for 5 or 10 minutes, it should be good enough.

Comment: hmm, I didn't know ORDER By RAND() is so bad for performance, I use it with listing images from photo gallery, maybe I should really learn and use caching.